# Creating a Spring Bean using FactoryMethod with variable arguments from Spring?

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

How can we create a bean using `FactoryMethod` with variable arguments.

```
 public class ConnectionFactoryClass {

    public static Connection composeConnection(final Property... properties) {
       ...
    }
 }
```

bean.xml

```
  <bean id="Connection"
    class="com.example.ConnectionFactoryClass"
    factory-method="composeConnection"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="Driver"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="Pool"/>
  </bean>
```

Spring is giving me an error saying,

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Connection' defined in file [./beans.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory method 'composeConnection'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<bean id="Connection"
    class="com.example.ConnectionFactoryClass"
    factory-method="composeConnection"
    scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg> 
        <array>
        <bean ref="Driver" />
            <bean ref="Pool" />
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
  </bean>
```

I think you are having a problem because the JVM turns a var arg params into an Object Array and you need to pass in a single paramater to the constructor which is the array of objects.  I have not tried the above xml so I might have typos in it, but something like the above should work.

Comment: For Java calls (like `applicationContext.getBean()`) the solution seems to be `new Object[]{new MyObject[]{myParam1, myParam2}}`because otherwise Java resolves the array into a vararg. Man that is ugly... Any better ideas?